# Boxplot by month

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, boxplot

I have a monthly temporal series with sales in this format (so there's no month or year column):

```
ts(data = Datos, start = c(2015,1), end = c(2020,12), frequency = 12)
```

How can I plot a multi-boxplot by month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the boxplots to display the variations for a specific month across the given five years period you can try:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tsibble)

ts(data = sample(100), start = c(2015,1), end = c(2020,12), frequency = 12) %>%  
  as_tsibble() %>% 
  mutate(month = as.factor(month(index))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(month, value)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]